# Replace same value on second row and on with 0

Tags: python, pandas

Is this possible to do in DataFrame Pandas?
I want to keep only first row value on the same column, replace second row, and on with 0

Input

```
Name--------Date-------Amount-----Labor  
A--------------1/1/1972-------5-------- 0.3  
A--------------1/1/1972-------5-------- 0.1  
A--------------1/1/1972-------5-------- 0.7  
A--------------1/1/1972-------1-------- 0.3     
B--------------7/2/1980-------1-------- 0.6  
B--------------7/2/1980-------1-------- 0.3  
B--------------7/2/1980-------1-------- 0.7  
C--------------6/9/1965-------4-------- 0.2    
C--------------6/9/1965-------4-------- 0.3  
C--------------6/9/1965-------4-------- 0.4
```

Output

```
Name--------Date-------Amount-----Labor  
A--------------1/1/1972-------5-------- 0.3  
A--------------1/1/1972-------0-------- 0.1  
A--------------1/1/1972-------0-------- 0.7  
A--------------1/1/1972-------0-------- 0.3     
B--------------7/2/1980-------1-------- 0.6  
B--------------7/2/1980-------0-------- 0.3  
B--------------7/2/1980-------0-------- 0.7  
C--------------6/9/1965-------4-------- 0.2    
C--------------6/9/1965-------0-------- 0.3  
C--------------6/9/1965-------0-------- 0.4
```

Comment: What if a `5` later occurs again?

Answer (score 1):

As simple as multiplying by a boolean mask.

```
df['Amount'] *= df['Amount'].ne(df['Amount'].shift())
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, that is possible. You can use [**`.duplicated(..)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) to construct a series that marks all duplicates with `True`. Then you thus can assign values with that mask:

```
df.loc[df['Amount'].duplicated(), 'Amount'] = 0
```

Or if you only want to set values that are duplicates in a "*sequence*", we can work with `.diff().eq(0)`:

```
df.loc[df['Amount'].diff().eq(0), 'Amount'] = 0
```

Comment: Depending on how OP wants to deal with duplicated numbers but not in sequence, this could either fail or work well. Ambiguous at this point ;]